# Python's eval() ignores discontinuities?

Tags: python, math, eval

I am building a Python graphing calculator, drawing functions by solving for `y` using `eval(function at x)` This works until I use a function with a removable discontinuity. Instead of returning something like `NaN`, eval just evaluates what the point *would* have been had it been continuous.

For example, if I evaluate `(x-2)/((x^2)-4)`, the function should technically be undefined at x=2, however using eval() at x=2 returns 0.25  instead of NaN, which is what the value WOULD be if the function was continuous (techincally the limit).

Is there a way for me to work around this issue and identify any removable discontinuities? In essence, if the denominator comes out to be zero

**Edit with code:**

```
COMPUTATION_DISTANCE = 0.001
# THE DISTANCE BETWEEN EACH X VALUE WHEN PLOTTING POINTS. EVENTUALLY WE CONNECT A LINE BETWEEN ALL POINTS SEPERATED BY A VALUE OF COMPUTATION_DISTANCE.
# IF THE GRAPH IS ZOOMED,  MULTIPLY THIS COMPUTATION DISTANCE BY A FACTOR OF THAT ZOOM
ASYMPTOTE = 2.0

#formula = "(x+2)**2" #just a fake formula to begin
formula = "(x-2)/((x**2)-4)" #just a fake formula to begin
view_size = 8.0




    def draw_graph(event):
        global alreadyGraphedDeriv #to prevent infinite loop of graphing deriv
        alreadyGraphedDeriv = False
        canvas.delete("all") #clear existing graph
        draw_grid()
        y_previous = 0.0
        x = view_size * -1 #start at the negative of the view_size. so x =-8. then the loop wil keep repeating until x =+8 giving u all the x values. the loop takes care of the y values
        while x <= view_size:
            try: 
                y = eval(formula) #evaluate y at every point x
                print(str(x) + ", " + str(y))
                #if(y>1000000000000 or y < 1000000000000): #finding asymptotes
                    #print("Asymptote at (" + str(x) + ", " + str(y) + ") ")

            except ValueError:
                y = 1000000000
                x = COMPUTATION_DISTANCE * view_size
                print('Value error')
                if eval(formula) < 0:
                    y *= -1
            except:
                print_formula("SYNTAX ERROR   ")
                print("syntax error")
                break
            try:
                draw_line(x - COMPUTATION_DISTANCE * view_size, y_previous, x, y, "black") #(previous x, previous y, new x, new y, color)
            except:
                print_formula("NON-INT PWR (dbl click ^)   ")
                break
            y_previous = y
            x += COMPUTATION_DISTANCE * view_size
            #print(" " + str(x - COMPUTATION_DISTANCE * view_size) + " " + str(y_previous) + " " + str(x) + " " + str(y) +  " black") 
            #(previous x, previous y, new x, new y, color)

        if alreadyGraphedDeriv is False:
            alreadyGraphedDeriv = True
            draw_derivative("event")
```

Take a look at the highlighted output. It has evaluated 0.25 as the solution for x=2.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the actual code? I'm having trouble replicating what you're describing.

Comment: Um, no it does not. with `x=2; print(eval('(x-2)/((x^2)-4)'))` will print `-0.0`. This is because `x^2` is `0`, since `^` is the bitwise and operator, not the exponentiation operator. If you use the exponentiation operator, `**` it would raise a `ZeroDivisionError`, not produce `nan`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `^` is the bitwise `xor` operator, not the `and` operator. `and` is `&`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Hey, I've updated my post with some code and a screenshot that shows it evaluating x=2.0 -> y=0.25, instead of raising a `ZeroDivisionError`. I would appreciate if you could take a look and let me know why that is.

Comment: @mypetlion I have edited to do so. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @RuchirBaronia your example is rather large and it sounds like you're concerned about a single computation, can you call that out?

Comment: A [mre] is the *shortest possible code* that reproduces the unexpected behavior when run without changes (to be a reproducer, that means it needs to be complete enough to run -- all `import`s and the like included). Ideally, this would mean you could eliminate everything related to graphing, everything related to iterating over a range (vs just hardcoding the one surprising input and contrasting actual and expected outputs when it's given), variables and values that aren't essential to the bug itself, etc.

Comment: which python version are you on? I guess, it's an older one

Answer (score 2):

The digit cutoff for the printed `y` values indicates you're on Python 2. (Python 3 would have showed a few more digits.)

On Python 2, `print`ing or `str`-ing a float truncates a bit more aggressively than on Python 3, so a value that *isn't quite* `2.0` can still show up as `2.0`. Your `x` isn't really `2.0`, because of accumulated rounding error, so your division *isn't quite* 0/0. It's dividing a very small number by a very small number, and the rounding error happens to work out so the output is `0.25` or very close.

If you `print(repr(x))` instead of `print(str(x))`, you'll see enough digits to make the rounding error obvious.

Also, get Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem. It can't really be solved in pure Python -- to handle discontinuities correctly, you'll need to do some algebraic analysis of the expression. You can, of course, write some functions to do that, but it might be a lot more convenient to use an existing system such as Sympy (https://sympy.org) for that.

You would want to look for discontinuities in the expression to be plotted, applying whatever heuristics a human would use, e.g. look for subexpressions in the denominator and see if they're zero anywhere. Also, you would want to see if any discontinuities are removable (as x = 2 in (x - 2)/(x**2 - 4) is removable since you can make a continuous function by just letting the result = 1/4 at x = 2). Finally you would plot each segment between discontinuities separately.

All in all, it sounds like a great project. Maybe a smart plotter like that would be something you could contribute to Sympy or another project, if they don't have one already.